# Are there valid cases in HTML/XML where tags would not be fully contained?

Tags: html, xml, sgml

I think in XML and HTML that having cross-scoped tags is not allowed. Maybe SGML allows it.  In XML/HTML though, are there any valid and allowed cases where this can occur?

Something like:

```
<p>This is <i>some <b>example</i> text</b> right here!</p>
```

Which would likely generate output like: "This is *some **example*** text right here!"

(Sidenote: the SO markdown parser apparently can handle it, who knew?)

```
"This is *some **example* text** right here!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think in XML and HTML that having cross-scoped tags is not allowed.

Correct

> Maybe SGML allows it.

It doesn't.

> In XML/HTML though, are there any valid and allowed cases where this can occur?

No. The markup just describes a DOM which is a tree of nodes. A node can only have one parent.

> "This is *some **example*** text right here!"

That is rendered as:

```
<p>"This is <em>some <strong>example</strong></em><strong> text</strong> right here!"</p>
```

Comment: Oh, I knew that the text I wrote up there wouldn't actually be rendered that way in HTML. It was just supposed to be a simple example of the concept, in case my terminology was wrong.  I was wondering if there exist any cases of such structuring being valid, but it sounds like you are saying there most definitely are not due to the underlying tree structure of the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

It's not allowed in HTML or XML. For a survey of approaches to handling non-hierarchic markup, the Wikipedia article is a good place to start:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_markup

Answer (score 1):

Overlapping tags like that is only possible as long as it's only tags in a text. As soon as the text is parsed into elements (HTML or XML), it's not possible to represent such a structure.

The concept of an elements is that it is a single entity, it's not a starting and ending point in a text.

As your SO markdown example shows, it's possible to use tags like that as long as it's just tags in a text. As Quentin showed, the SO text parser has to translate that into a non-overlapping structure to be able to create valid HTML code for it.